# Is the database the best location for my backend (API) settings?

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, security

Is the application main database the best place to store its settings? Are there any security reasons to no do that?

For instance, to store what Rate (%) is charged in every transaction in some e-commerce.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Which DB are you talking about? and what sort of settings are you talking about? can you please clarify?

Comment: Hard to say. We don't know how critical the data is and what other processes are running on the db. This question needs more focus.

Comment: Sorry to be so general. I'm building an API for my app. Currently is using Postgres as DB. The application is using Express on top of NodeJS. The settings I'm talking about is for example how much money is charged for the app service.

Comment: You could save settings like that in your DB, but you'll probably want to manage the permissions to read/change them carefully. Let's say that you don't want anyone to change them, but allow everyone to read them, I would put them in a table with RO permissions to the user you are using in your server, and have an admin user for changes, but again, this is a complicated question and you can feel free to edit your question to add details for better answers